# How to use Socket io with Koa route get and post methods and with Koa-passport?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, koa, passport-local

My app is simple login registration app.
Using Koa 2.0, Koa-route, Koa-passport, passport-local, passport-google-auth.

I want to use chat functionality with this app and want to create Socket.io connection when user is logged in and disconnect when logout or exit.

But if I use socket.io then my other functions are not working.

I can route through pages but  route.post methods are not working,

and also how can I access ctx.passport.user in io.on

I am using swig for templating.

Comment: Have you tried googling "koa websocket"? It seems that there are at least 3  `npm` packages for that: [koa-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-websocket), [koa-socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-socket) and [koa-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-ws).

Comment: ok thanks... i ll try both